# Export data from python to csv

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I want to do some calculations with python and export the data afterwards into a csv file. This works fine. But it writes everything into the same cell. So, I wanted to ask if it is possible to do the same just write every value in a cell. The way I export is the code below:

```
import csv

f = open('C:///Users///....csv', 'a', newline='')

row = [x, y,z]

writer = csv.writer(f)

writer.writerow(row)
f.close
```

Like this I get one cell with the value [x,y,z], but I would like to have each of x,y,z in a seperate cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
row = [x, y,z]
with open("C:///Users///....csv", mode='a') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(row)
```